# MySQL: ALTER IGNORE TABLE with DROP INDEX

Tags: mysql, alter-table, mysql-error-1091

I have many databases and in each I have table `names`. In some I have UNIQUE KEY named `name1` and in others the same UNIQUE KEY is named `name2`. I want to standard this name so I prepared 3 queries to run on each database:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `names`
    DROP INDEX `name1`;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `names`
    DROP INDEX `name2`;
ALTER TABLE `names`
    ADD UNIQUE `new_name` (`name`, `surname`);
```

But I got error:

```
SQL Error (1091): Can't DROP 'name1'; check that column/key exists
```

How can I make one set of queries to run on each database?

Comment: So what is the question? How to ignore error, or how to run query in each database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attempt to ignore errors if you're executing your SQL script file from command line:

```
mysql -f -u username -p password -e 'source script.sql'
```

EDIT

Thanks to Ike, the correct way to do this is:

```
mysql -f -u username -p password < script.sql
```

Comment: Actually that will not work if there is more than one error. It will abort after the first error. The proper way to ignore errors in script.sql is: `mysql -f -u username -p password < script.sql`